# Excel on Mac and Windows have different row height / column width ratios

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, compatibility

I find it odd that the same workbook in Excel is stretched horizontally on the mac. This is a slight problem, because the word wrapping changes, sparklines become squished, and the appearance becomes off.

I checked the row height and on windows, it has '14.25' (19 pixels) and this becomes '13' (0.16 in) on Mac. Much shorter! '11.43' (85 pixels) for column width on windows became '11.33' (0.87 in) on mac.

Is this stretching common for everyone? Is there a way to get it to look the same on both platforms?

Comment: I am facing same problem. Column width in Mac Excel is 10.67 and same file opened in windows excel, its 10.86.

Answer (score 0):

I wish, although there might be workaround, I gave up. 
Whenever a client gives me any office file whether it's Excel or anything else, I completely bypass Office for Mac and open the file in [Excel online](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx). Works for most uses, unless you're a hardcore Excel user.